# Is there any standard way to get the last SMTP return code, using a generic implementation of javamail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am probably just asking for confirmation of what I believe will be a negative answer.
I've read the code and search the documentation, and it seems to be not the case.

Additionally, as there seems also to be no 'non-standard' way to do this when using the gnu freemail implementation either, I am wondering what other people do?

The only thing that seems left to me is to hope that the exception.getMessage() function always gives me the last SMTP server response, and that I can parse out the response code; 550, 250 etc. Except, i can't find any documentation to say that I can expect this from a SendFailedException or MessagingException (although, from tests, this appears to be the case).

How else can you code in logic to handle the various failure cases ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to do this, but the SMTP provider in the JavaMail reference implementation from Oracle has a way to do this.